# Prove that $n!+1$ and $(n+1)!+1$ are relatively prime for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am self-studying number theory and went back to an earlier section and was not able to solve this. I have tried many things in order to write it as a linear combination equal to 1. I really just want a hint because I haven't been stuck this long so I may just be overlooking something simple. Thanks.

Comment: Any common divisor divides the difference $(n+1)!+1 - (n!+1) = (n+1)!-n! = n!(n)$. But no nontrivial factor of $n!(n)$ divides $n!+1$.

Comment: You might find this past MSE post fruitful -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25688/prove-that-gcdn1-n11-1

Comment: This problem is kind of calling out for a proof by contradiction. That plus @ArturoMagidin 's comment is all you need.

Comment: @stuartstevenson: Why do a proof by contradiction, when you can do a direct proof that any common divisor divides $1$?

Comment: I got to the point of equating the difference to $n!(n)$ but never made the connection that none of the nontrivial factors would divide $n!+1$. Oops. Thank you all.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's faster.

Comment: @stuartstevenson: Not really;you have to add an extra hypothesis at the top (“assume not”), and then deduce a contradiction from the conclusion you reached without every using that assumption, adding “but this contradicts our assumption that we had a nontrivial factor”. Sounds like two extra steps to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: use $1=n!+1-(n-1)!n,\,n=(n+1)(n!+1)-((n+1)!+1)$ to write $1$ in the desired form.