# Prove that for every natural number $n$ we have $\gcd(n! + 1, (n + 1)! + 1) = 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, gcd-and-lcm

I know that we are gonna need to use one of the identities that the $\gcd$ is equal to but I can't remember one that would be useful for this problem.  Any help?

Comment: Bézout. $ $ $ $

Comment: Duplicate, [full answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/6385/23500)

Comment: Can you think of an integer $m$ with the property that if you multiply $n!+1$ with $m$, you will get something that is relatively close to $(n+1)!+1$? That gives you a first step of Euclid.

Comment: Opps, sorry y'all.  Didn't see that one.  Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just note that a common divisor $d$ of $(n+1)!+1$ and  $n!+1$ divides also
$$
(n+1) (n!+1) - ((n+1)!+1) = (n+1)! + n+1 - (n+1)! - 1 = n.
$$
And then $\gcd(n!+1, n ) = 1$, as $n!+1$ divided by $n$ leaves remainder $1$.